# Parallel computing in R (Windows): changing code from foreach %do% to foreach %dopar%

Tags: r, parallel-processing, regression, multivariate-testing

I have written a code to run several time-series rolling-regressions for multiple securities. Since the number of securities is more than 10,000, and having more than 200 rolling windows for each security, the runtime for a sequential set-up (using foreach %do%) is about 30min.

I would like to implement foreach %dopar% for parallel computing instead, using the "doParrallel" backend. Simply changing %do% with %dopar% in the code doesn't do the trick. I am very new to this parrallel computing method, and would hope to get some help.

Here is the foreach %do% code:

```
sec = ncol(ret.zoo)
num.factors = 2
rows = nrow(ret.zoo) - 60 + 1
beta.temp = matrix(nc = num.factors + 1, nr = sec*rows)
gvkey.vec = matrix(nc = 1, nr = sec*rows)

d = 1
foreach(i=1:sec) %do% {
      df = merge(ret.zoo[,i], data)
      names(df) <- c("return", names(data))
      gvkey = substr(colnames(ret.zoo)[i],2,9)

      reg = function(z) {
          z.df = as.data.frame(z)
          ret = z.df[,which(names(z.df) ==  "return")]
          ret.no.na = ret[!is.na(ret)]
          if(length(ret.no.na) >= 30) {
             coef(lm(return ~ VAL + SIZE, data = as.data.frame(z), na.action = na.omit))
          }
          else {
             as.numeric(rep(NA,num.factors + 1))   ## the "+1" is for the intercept value
          }     
     }

     beta = rollapply(df, width = 60, FUN = reg, by.column = FALSE, align = "right")
     beta.temp[d:(d+rows-1),] = beta
     gvkey.vec[d:(d+rows-1),] = gvkey
     d = d+rows
}
beta.df = data.frame(secId = gvkey.vec, date = rep(index(beta), sec), beta.temp)
colnames(beta.df) <- c("gvkey", "date", "intercept", "VAL", "SIZE")
```

In order to enable parallel computing using %dopar%, I have called and registered the backend "doParallel".

Thank you very much!

**UPDATE**

Here is my first try:

```
library(doParallel) ## parallel backend for the foreach function
registerDoParallel()

sec = ncol(ret.zoo)
num.factors = 2
rows = nrow(ret.zoo) - 60 + 1

result <- foreach(i=1:sec) %dopar% {
    library(zoo)
    library(stats)

    df = merge(ret.zoo[,i], data)
    names(df) <- c("return", names(data))
    gvkey = substr(colnames(ret.zoo)[i],2,9)

    reg = function(z) {
        z.df = as.data.frame(z)
        ret = z.df[,which(names(z.df) ==  "return")]
        ret.no.na = ret[!is.na(ret)]
        if(length(ret.no.na) >= 30) {
            coef(lm(return ~ VAL + SIZE, data = as.data.frame(z), na.action = na.omit))
        }
        else {
            as.numeric(rep(NA,num.factors + 1))   ## the "+1" is for the intercept value
        }   
    }

    rollapply(df, width = 60, FUN = reg, by.column = FALSE, align = "right")
}
beta.df = do.call('combine', result)
```

This works perfectly up until the end of the loop. However, the `beta.df = do.call('combine', result)` gives the following error: `Error in do.call("combine", result) : could not find function "combine"`.

How can I combine the output of result. Now it is a list rather than a dataframe.

Thanks,

Comment: There is actually no "explicit" error. But the matrix "beta.temp" has only NA values when %dopar% is used. When %do% is used instead, the beta.temp has regression coefficient values when appropriate, and NA values when appropriate. I am definitely doing something wrong by just replacing %do% by %dopar%

Comment: I believe that the way I allocate the results to beta.temp (by incrementing d) is wrong when %dopar% is used. It works fine with %do%. I am just not sure how to do it differently in the context of parallel computing.

Comment: You can try to return `beta` and `gvkey`, and `rbind` them outside the loop.

Comment: Even gvkey only has NA values, as it is incremented with d as well :S

Comment: I tried something similar to what you suggested. It is working perfectly, up to combining the final results, that's where it gives an error. Please refer to my updated question above. Thanks.

Comment: The other issue is that it seems that the parallel computing (as done above) is lower than the sequential (using %do%)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way of combining the results from the different clusters into a dataframe (very efficient from a runtime standpoint):

```
lstData <- Map(as.data.frame, result)
dfData <- rbindlist(lstData)
beta.df = as.data.frame(dfData)
```

Comment: Foreach has a .combine argument ..check there